# How create netbeans plug-in?

Tags: plugins, netbeans

How to make a simple plugin that runs at netbeans startup and writes something to the console and all.
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Google did the trick:

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.html

Comment: This is not what I wanted.
This plug-in requires a form and pressing "enter".

I want that plug-in run automatically when netbeans started.

Comment: It's a start though, if you are creating it like your post suggests then you could at least take some elements from this.